# Flyway migration failed using H2

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, flyway

My spring boot application uses H2 for its tests and I also added flyway maven plugin and dependencies (flyway-core and flyway-spring-test).
This is my application-test.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/my_db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.flyway.user=sa
spring.flyway.password=
spring.flyway.schemas=PUBLIC
```

and my application-prod.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.flyway.user=${spring.datasource.username}
spring.flyway.password=${spring.datasource.password}
spring.flyway.schemas=my_db
```

and I have `V1__desc.sql` in `src/main/resources/db/migration` which is flyway's default dir. I get no errors & exception while running my program using MySQL and I see my tables and `flyway_schema_history`. But I get this exception while running the spring boot default context loading test:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: 
Detected failed migration to version 1 (my_db)
```

I even changed my flyway location to somewhere else but it didn't change. Can sb plz help?

Comment: "Detected failed migration to version 1" => There was a failed migration before!

Comment: Agree with comment above -- Vfiles are checksum'd and that's the error that's given when a migration file has been modified. I normally use an in-memory version, but I set MYSQL mode a bit differently, may help - `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:my_db;MODE=MYSQL`

Answer (score -1):

Change fylway version, that works on my Project...
if it not works pls post a bigger console log

Comment: Which version did you change to?

Comment: the plugin version by example from 5.0.1 to 5.0.0

Answer (score -2):

I would say:

Set flyway to debug mode.
Check the content of the sql script.

Best.

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer!

Comment: Where should I set flyway to debug mode? I set `spring.flyway.stream=true` but I don't see any sql statement being executed while running/debugging.